# Node packages error after migrating project to different folder

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio

Using Angular with an ASP.NET MVC project and ive moved the codebase to another path on my hard drive.  When I build, I get errors complaining about not being able to find packages.  I dont think this is so much of an Angular issue (using System.js module loader), but rather a Node issue related to finding packages.

The fix so far has been to simply delete everything in node_modules and get them again.  Is there a way to avoid having to do this?  Otherwise, if I check my code into our source control system and someone else pulls it down, they will run into this issue as well.

[update]
When I am making a copy of the project, it includes the node_modules as well.  I intend to check in these into source control as well, so that we can control when packages get updated and the dependency issues that might be caused.

[update 2]
Well I think I need to go back and review what Im doing.  I never liked the idea of keeping node_modules in source to begin with and if I can find a way to manage "breaking changes" due to package updates, then I can forego the mess and bloat from keeping node_modules in my source control system.
https://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-node-package-manager/

Comment: Check the project path to build config. Whether it is static or dynamic.

Comment: Im not sure which setting you are referring to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When someone else pull the code or when you move your code in other folder YOU HAVE TO RUN A `NPM NISTALL`  command .. so it can download the packages ..

if you have already downloded them ..don't worry to do a NPM  INSTALL cause it takes them from the cache ....

for other people they need first time to download them for first time

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: Not if Im checking all the node packages into source as well.  Im doing this because our team doesnt want to get every new update that might break other things.

Comment: it's impossible .. they're with a verison and a file like package-lock.json (after 8.00 node version) .... which block your version as same your're using

Comment: In your project, is there you mentioned static path, please rectify and dont worry about your node modules it doesn't rely on your hard disc path its rely on your project path.
I hope you understand.